# AutoLayout with Scrollview and UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

So I have a `UIViewController` with a bunch of `IBOutlet`'s elements placed on a `UIScrollView`(ContentView). All are using **Auto Layout** and are working perfect except for the `UITextView`. Due to its position I cannot figure out what constraints to add to the bottom of the `UITextView` so the scroll view will notice it's full size depending on the text. Currently the `UITextView` is underneath/off the view.

This is how the view is composed.

[image: This is how the view is composed.]

Can't figure out the last constraint for the `UITextview`
[image: Can't figure out the last constraint for the UITextview]

The constraints on the UITextView are as follows:

Trailing Space to: Superview
(Equals: 8)

Leading Space to: SuperView 
(Equals: 9)

Top Space to: MapView
(Equals: 70)

These constraints are exactly the way I want the `UITextView` positioned. It's just the bottom constraint I can't figure out so that the content size is of `UIScrollView` big enough for the `UITextView`.

If there's anymore information I need to provide please let me know. I've been stuck with this the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure "Scrolling Enabled" of your `UITextView` is disable then
add five constraints(leading, trailing, top, bottom, height) on `UITextView` and add an `IBOutlet` on the view controller for the `UITextView` height constraint. Finally just change the `UITextView` height constraint programmatically.